# Question about the Ember tutorial, why the link http://localhost:4200/rentals/grand-old-mansion does not work

Tags: ember.js

I am learning ember now. I follow the tutorial to build a web app.

In part 2 of the tutorial, the Route Params section the URL as follow:

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-2/route-params/

I found something strange.

The test case for the below link does not pass.

http://localhost:4200/rentals/grand-old-mansion

I found that if I click the link from the root (i.e. /),
it can shows the rental correctly.

And then, if I refresh the page, it does not work.
The error message as below:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: No model was found for 'rental' and no schema handles the type
```

I checked all files that do not have typo error.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is probably, that your `model` hook is not implemented. A bit context for this:

The important thing to understand here is, that if you create a link like `<LinkTo @route="rental" @model={{@rental}}>` and click on it, the `model()` hook on the `rental` route fill *not* be executed. Instead whatever you pass to `@model` will be used. The same is also true when doing `Router#transitionTo('rental', model)`.

So this works because you alreday have the data loaded. However when you reload the `model` hook of the `rental` route gets executed. And because you didn't implement it the default model hook will be used. And this one is quite magical. It checkes the name of your dynamic segment, which is `rental_id`. And if its `somethind_id` it will basically `return this.store.findRecord('something', params.something_id)`. So in your case the default model hook is equivalent to this:

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.findRecord('rental', params.rental_id);
}
```

but you dont have an ember data model named `rental` and so you get the error:

> Error: No model was found for 'rental'

So to fix it you have to check that your `model` hook is present and implemented correctly.

---

One important note:

`<LinkTo` and `transitionTo` *will* execute the `model()` hook if you pass a string or an number.
So you can do `<LinkTo @route="rental" @model={{@rental.id}}>` and it *will* execute the model hook, using that you passed to `@model` as dynamic segment and not the model value. I personally have seen a few apps that *always* pass the id, so they dont have the error you had without noticing. And personally thats what I would recommend.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to ember. Would you mind elaborate more about how to check the model hook?

Comment: show the code of your route. check if its named correctly. is there code present?

Comment: Do you mean the file app/router.js?

Comment: Finally, I found that the file app/routes/rental.js is missing. After that, I follow the instruction on the tutorial web page to add this file, it works